Error: couldn't execute function: exec: "ksops": executable file not found in $PATH $ kustomize build --enable-alpha-plugins --enable-exec
getting this error message when implementin ksops
i change path path of kops , which is "/usr/local/bin/ksops" and also getting an error that "Error: couldn't execute function: fork/exec /usr/local/bin/ksops: no such file or directory"
